# Blazor InputText: conditionally rendering an attribute

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

Blazor vRC1

I'm looking for a straightforward technique on how to conditionally render an attribute within an `<InputText>` (or any of the input components for that matter).  This used to be simple in MVC Razor, where you'd just write the conditional logic within the `@(...)` statement.  Now, writing `@(...)` has different meaning in the Razor syntax.

For example, I'd like to conditionally output the `autofocus` HTML attribute for `InputText`.

```
<InputText 
 @bind-Value="@TextProperty"
 @(MyModel.isAutoFocus ? "autofocus" : "") <-  This is invalid razor syntax!
/>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could try below code:

```
<InputText  @bind-Value="@TextProperty"  autofocus="@(MyModel.isAutoFocus)"  />
```

Refer to https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/10122

Comment: The presence of the autofocus attribute enables the feature. I need to conditionally write out the attribute, not the value.

Comment: @Aaron Hudon  I have tried and find that If set  `autofocus= true`,it will show as `autofocus` in the input on page, if  `autofocus= false`, it will not show as attribute for the input.Maybe you could open browser F12 to check the result?

Comment: Thanks - I might just have to fall back to this, but the original question still stands, how to conditionally output an attribute.

Comment: @Aaron Hudon I understand now but I think blazor does not support that yet.Good luck...

Answer (score 34):

As it turns out, Blazor will *not* render the attribute if the value of the attribute is `false` or `null`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components?view=aspnetcore-3.0#conditional-html-element-attributes

> HTML element attributes are conditionally rendered based on the .NET
>   value. If the value is false or null, the attribute isn't rendered. If
>   the value is true, the attribute is rendered minimized.

```
<InputText @bind-Value="@TextProperty" autofocus="@MyModel.isAutoFocus" />
```

Comment: Of interesting note - this also works for the `disabled` or `selected` tags which normally don't equal anything. E.g. `<select @bind="selectValue" disabled="isDisabled">`

Comment: @AlbatrossCafe it doesn't work on `disabled`

Comment: It doesn't work on the ```form``` attribute on buttons either.

Comment: Works for the readonly attribute of the built-in InputText component.

Answer (score 22):

This could potentially be achieved with the @attributes tag. [See more here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components?view=aspnetcore-3.0#attribute-splatting-and-arbitrary-parameters)

Basically, you can add an @attributes tag to your InputText. This can bind to a parameter, or to a handy little method.

```cs
<InputText @bind-Value="@TextProperty" @attributes="HandyFunction()" />

@code{
    Dictionary<string,object> HandyFunction()
    {
        var dict = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        if(MyModel.isAutoFocus) dict.Add("autofocus",true);
        return dict;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, although nowhere near as straightforward as it should be like in earlier editions of Razor.

Comment: This also works if you need to conditionally set a parameter on a blazor component like if you need to pass a render fragment through.

Answer (score 0):

### Add or Remove Attributes in HTML Using Blazor

To *add* or *remove* HTML attribute via Blazor logic, I suggest you use the "attribute splatting" feature (`<input @attributes=... />`) built into Microsoft Blazor.

*Why?* Its better to modify the **attributes dictionary** on the element for all attributes assigned to your `<input>` and using the event `OnInitialized()`, rather than cobbling attributes inside the HTML, as the `@attributes` collection could have custom attributes assigned to the component in its tag helper or added elsewhere via the `@attributes` value on prerender events that get erased or conflict. This code below makes sure your attributes are added into the pipeline of processes for **all attributes** assigned to your HTML element that the `@attributes` feature manages.

```
<input @attributes="MyAttributes" />

@code {
    
    [Parameter(CaptureUnmatchedValues = true)]
    public Dictionary<string, object> MyAttributes { get; set; }

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        // CONDITIONALLY ADD/REMOVE AN HTML ATTRIBUTE

        // Remove
        if (MyAttributes.ContainsKey("style"))
        {
            if ({Add Your Conditional Logic Here})
            {
                MyAttributes.Remove("style");
            }        
         }

         // Add
         if ({Add Your Conditional Logic Here})
         {
              var MyAttributes = new Dictionary<string, object> {{"data-helloworld", "Hello World!"}};

             // This adds your new attribute created above,
             // BUT prevents duplicates by honoring the first
             // or original attribute, if it exists.

             MyAttributes = MyAttributes.Concat(newAttribute)
            .GroupBy(i => i.Key)
            .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.First().Value);
             }
         }
     }
}
```

### Simple Ways to Add An Attribute in Blazor

Btw...I use these techniques to force a **single** *name-value* attribute pair into HTML when modifying a Blazor component. It's not pretty, but it's all we are stuck with using their "attribute splatting" model.

This code below becomes `<div style="color:blue;">Blue Text</div>`:

```
<div @attributes="MyCSS">Blue Text</div>

@code {
    private Dictionary<string,object> MyCSS{ get; set; } = 
    new Dictionary<string,object> {{ "style","color:blue;" }};
}
```

If you just want to update a known attribute value in Blazor, you can also do this:

```
<div style="@MyCSS">Blue Text</div>

@code {
    private string MyCSS= "color:blue;";
}
```